# Embed table into longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I try to create a latex table from a yaml file (with python) to create a specification document. My idea is to create a longtable and put in the first column the specification number and in the second column the title and the description.
[image: Specification entry]

In the yaml specification I have also tables and I would like to embedd them into this longtable. For this I tried to use directly tabular, but for long texts the pagebrake is not done correctly.

How do I embedd the table correctly in the long table? The embedded table shall also do a pagebrake. The problem is that it is not possible to embedd a longtable into a longtable

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{german,longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{11cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{=}{SPEC\_601} & \textbf{Specification 1}\\
        \cline{2-2}
        & Description of Specification 1\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{=}{SPEC\_602} & \textbf{Specification 2}\\
        \cline{2-2}
        & The table contains the description of the specification:
        \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|}
            \hline 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed. Neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida. Nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas. Ut ornare lectus sit amet. In dictum non consectetur a erat nam at lectus. & This is another long text\\
            \hline 
            Test2 & Test2\\
            \hline
            Test3 & Test3 \\
            \hline
            Test4 & Test4 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{=}{SPEC\_603} & \textbf{Specification 3}\\
        \cline{2-2}
        & Description of Specification 3
        \begin{tabular}{|l| l|}
            \hline 
            Pin Number & Pin Description\\
            1 & Description of Pin 1 \\
            2 & Description of Pin 2 \\
            \hline 
            
        \end{tabular}
        \\
        \hline
        
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you aware, that long table can break only between rows? Inserting table in one cells means, that this cell can be huge and possible points for breaking of (main) table can be very rare.

Comment: I have seen that it does not break. Should I then embed the table directly into the longtable instead of inserting a tabular?